# Prove gradient descent converges to a local minimum

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I would like to have a proof that indeed, the gradient descent converges to a local minimum if it exists, for a differentiable function with Lipschitz continuous derivative $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$. Say also that the function is bounded from below. One dimension is enough for the purposes of the question.

The gradient descent algorithm is given by, with some initial condition $y_0$
$$y_{n+1}=y_n-g(n)f'(y_n)$$

It's quite clear that $g(n)$ should be chosen so that $g(n)\rightarrow0$ and $\sum g(n)$ diverges. Otherwise we may have a situation in which the algorithm jumps around the minimum or gets stuck. A natural choice is $g(n)=\frac{1}{n}$. How to prove the result - and is there a constructive proof?

Comment: @Moo Assumes Lipschitz continuity on the derivative and further convexity of the function. Is this the best we can do?

Comment: @Moo It is stated in the question, $f$ is continuously differentiable. However, this is perhaps missing the point of the question since I am merely a user of the algorithm. I want to know when the optimizer converges, when not and if not why not.

Comment: @Moo e.g. I thought the result in the question is true but perhaps not...

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what do you mean by "constructive" in this context?

Comment: Also it looks like your question may be missing some assumptions. For instance, you have not assumed that a local min exists. Another common assumption is Lipschitz continuity of the gradient.

Comment: @Zim So far I only managed to show that it indeed did not work. Perhaps now with the different assumptions... By constrictive I mean a direct proof that also does not rely on other non-direct proofs such as intermediate value theorem etc.

Comment: Ok cool. It looks like your condition on $g(n)$ may work but I think you're allowed to have more general step size selection strategies. You can check out, e.g. the Goldstein-Armijo method or the Wolfe condition for some commonly used step size strategies. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe_conditions is a good start

Comment: @Zim Thanks... I was able to prove that $x_n$ decreases every step... but is there no more general conditions? It seems like this condition is quite restrictive.